# JOIN & List Last Records per an ID

Tags: mysql

There are two tables:

```
SELECT id,customer FROM records;
SELECT user_id,call_date FROM call_history
```

Matching columns are:

```
records.id = call_history.user_id
```

The `call_history` table has call logs for customers. 
There can be one or more `call_history` rows per customer.

I need to find when they called last time (for each customer).

For ex. `userid=1` called twice, June 16 and July 20. Result must give me July 20, but I need to do the same for all customers from records table.

That is what I tried but it didn't work:

```
SELECT a.id, FROM_UNIXTIME(b.call_date,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i') AS lastcall
FROM records a
INNER JOIN call_history b ON a.id=b.user_id
GROUP BY a.id ORDER BY b.call_date DESC;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Does this meet your requirements?

```
SELECT
    r.id,
    r.customer,
    MAX(ch.call_date) AS lastcall
FROM
    records AS r
INNER JOIN
    call_history AS ch ON ch.user_id = r.id
GROUP BY
    r.id,
    r.customer
```